# read CSV file and store data in matrix form using emgucv C#

Tags: c#, emgucv

```
 Matrix<float> trainData = new Matrix<float>(150, 7);
```

this is the matrix Of 150x7 . now if i have a csv file containing 7 fields AND 150 rows(comma separated) that i want to load in this matrix. if any of done the same or related task then reply.. thank you

Answer (score 0):

You actually don't need EmguCV for that.

You can simply read the file in c# and fill the matrix. The code will be something like this.

```
 int rowNumber=0;   
 Matrix<float> trainData = new Matrix<float>(150, 7);
 using (var rd = new StreamReader("filename.csv"))
    {
        while (!rd.EndOfStream)
        {
            var splits = rd.ReadLine().Split(';');

            trainData[rowNumber,0]= splits[0];
            trainData[rowNumber,1]= splits[1];
            trainData[rowNumber,2]= splits[2];
            trainData[rowNumber,3]= splits[3];
            trainData[rowNumber,4]= splits[4];
            trainData[rowNumber,5]= splits[5];
            trainData[rowNumber,6]= splits[6];
// You might want to explicitly cast the values to float before storing
            rowNumber++;   // to move to the next row
            }
        }
```